# Empty Object in req body on post request

Tags: node.js, express

I'm having trouble with getting the proper data out of req.body

When I fetch a request to the server I get this in my console (Ex: 'Wash dishes' as the value for the input)

```
// console log
{}
{ item: 'Wash dishes' }
```

an empty object first and then the item I specified.

html file

```
<form autocomplete="off" id="formform" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="item" placeholder="Add new item..." required id="inputinput" >
            <button type="submit">Add Item</button>
</form>
```

test-w-fetch.js

```
let newForm = document.getElementById('formform');

newForm.addEventListener('submit', (evt) =>{
  let item = document.getElementById('inputinput');
  let todo = {item: item.value};


  fetch('/todo', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: todo
  }).then( (response) => {
    return response.json();
  }).then((data) =>{

      location.reload();
  }).catch((err) =>{
    console.log(`There's an ${err}!!`);
  });

  return false;
});
```

Here's my POST route on the server

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/todo', (req, res) => {
    // Need to get data from the view and add it to mongodb
    console.log(req.body);

    let newItem = new Todo(req.body);

    newItem.save( (err, data) =>{
        if (err) throw err;

        res.json(data);
    }); 
});
```

Other option I have tried was taking error checking req.body.item property, storing it into a new object, and passing it to the database, but the empty object is still going through the body and getting saved to the database

Comment: Why do you have a location.reload()? when the submit process reload the browser automatically

Comment: @Angel I was following a NetNinja tutorial and it had that. I just removed it and on submission the page went to a page only displaying the JSON data I submitted. When I put it back in, the page reloads normally with the updated to-do list item. In such case, would it be better to redirect the route to the same url instead of using location.reload?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try to is use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to te to see if the issue is server or client side. Would help narrow down the troubleshooting surface area.